# onchange attribute missing on one particular server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am having some issues with an Asp.Net webforms site that seem to be related to a particular server. For instance when I try to redirect the user after a successful login (as seen by audit entry in database) it simply returns them to the login page again. Another hint at the problem seems to be that certain elements are not rendering correctly in the HTML.

Source code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtUserName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
```

View-Source on bad server:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtUserName" type="text" id="MainContent_txtUserName" />
```

View-Source on development server:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtUserName" type="text" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$txtUserName\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="MainContent_txtUserName" style="width:200px;" />
```

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are u sure it's server related? Is the same browser used in both cases?

Comment: Are you sure you running the same code on both servers?

Comment: I am guessing here, but have you checked whether the development server and the bad server are running the same ASP.NET version?

Comment: This software is installed on a number of machines and this is the only one with this issue. It is definitely the same code on both servers.

Comment: I am using IE on both servers. The server is running .Net framework 4.0. My dev environment is on 4.5.1. ANY suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the app on different framework versions and this is most probably causing your problems.

Make sure the server .NET version and the .NET version you are developing in are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the problem is related to Browser Definitions. This server was not up to date on its Windows Updates seeming to have never been updated. Doing that resolved this issue.